# wand-py + ImageMagick scaling issue

Tags: python, django, svg, imagemagick, wand

I'm using wand-py (0.3.3) and ImageMagick(versions below) in an application to customize designs from source SVGs.  I'm currently running into an issue with different versions of ImageMagick returning rather different results, and I'm hoping somebody out there in Python / django land has an idea.

The source svg looks like this:
[image: source file]

Using ImageMagick 6.6.2-6 2012-08-17 Q16, the cropped / slightly scaled output looks like this (not perfect, but not terrible):

[image]

However, using ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2012-08-17 Q16, the output looks like this:

[image]

The actual call I'm making is simply:

```
with WandImage(blob = self.cover_binary, resolution = 300) as img:
    img.type = self.png_image_type #truecolor
    img.depth = self.png_image_depth #8
    img.resize(self.png_width, self.png_height)
    self.png_output = img.make_blob('png')
```

I've tried tons of variations of `img.resize()` with different blur and filter settings, (blur values between 0 and 1, filter values of none, triangle, point, lanczos, lanczossharp), but I'm just not able to get the preview rendering with the small line detail.  I'm at my wits end and about to go with a solution that I don't like, and am hoping somebody out there might be able to give me some insight on what I'm missing here.  It already took me a few hours just to realize that ImageMagick is likely the culprit since that's literally the only thing different between my local box running the older version and the staging box that has the newer version.

Comment: This answer comes nearly 2 years late, but yes, there are significant image quality differences between versions of ImageMagick. In Spree's tutorial for getting paperclip set up on Heroku (https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/heroku.html#paperclip-image-quality-issues), they use this image to illustrate the difference between different versions of ImageMagick:

https://i.imgur.com/dqeNdlW.png

It's pretty noticeable! Anyway, cheers.